# R: How to find the mean across categories of variables

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, mean, sapply

I have a data frame with about 50 numeric variables. I want to create a new column with values for the mean of a certain number of these variables which fall into the same category. So for example, I might want to create a new variable called `df$mean_weight` which contains values for the averages across rows of respondents' `df$weight1`, `df$weight2`, `df$weight3`. And the same thing with height variables etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
find_mean = function(...) {
  input_list = list(...)
  output_list = sapply(input_list,mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  return(output_list)
}

df$mean_weight = find_mean(df$weight1, df$weight2, df$weight3)
```

The problem is this gives me an error saying the replacement has fewer rows than my original data. For some reason this error isn't present when I try height variables with the same code, however.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error. The function works fine for a sample dataset I generate.

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(200), ncol = 5));
colnames(df) <- paste0("weight", seq(1:5));

# Your function
find_mean = function(...) {
  input_list = list(...)
  output_list = sapply(input_list,mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  return(output_list)
}

find_mean(df$weight1, df$weight2, df$weight3)
#[1] 0.4736851 0.5569710 0.4300163
```

You can also achieve the same output in a single line:

```
sapply(c("weight1", "weight2", "weight3"), function(x) mean(df[, x]))
#  weight1   weight2   weight3
#0.4736851 0.5569710 0.4300163
```